# Prove that $\forall\, x>0$ exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $ \frac{1}{2^n}<x$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

My teacher gave me this question and I don't really know where to start, she said we might need to use the Archimedes' principle but I don't know how to do it.
I would be great if you could help me.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: But $\frac{1}{2^n} \leq \frac{1}{2}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$... Maybe you want $\frac{1}{2^n}<x$?

Answer (score 2):

The question seems incorrectly stated, for example if you take $x=1$ there is no $n$ such that $1/2^n > x$, you probably meant $<$.

For that problem, for every $x>0$ show that there exist an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{2^n} < x$, we need to find an $n$ such that $\frac{1}{2^n}$ is as small as we like. Turning it around, given $x >0$ we want to find $n$ such that $2^n > \frac{1}{x}$.

A little useful trick here may be to notice that $2^n > n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. So in other words if we can find an $n$ such that $n > \frac{1}{x}$, then $2^n > n > \frac{1}{x}$. Can you see how to use the Archimedean property to find such an $n$?

Comment: Yes I understood, thank you very much